# SSH Reverse tunneling in Android

Tags: java, android, ssh

I am using SSHJ library to establish reverse ssh tunnel but no luck ..

```
Error: Unable to resolve host name
```

Code used :

```
final SSHClient ssh = new SSHClient(new AndroidConfig());
Command cmd = null;
// Adds a nullHostKeyVerifier
ssh.addHostKeyVerifier(new NullHostKeyVerifier());
// default port number
int pn = 22;
// connect to the machine
try {
    String pemkey = "/mnt/sdcard/lamp.pem";
    ssh.loadKeys(pemkey);
    ssh.connect("-R 8080:localhost:8080 root@54.X.X.X ",pn);
    // Authenticate with the password entered
    // start a new session
    final Session session = ssh.startSession();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("message", e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Comment: `connect` takes only a hostname, e.g. `ssh.connect("54.X.X.X");` I don't know how to do such a reverse tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

consider using [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) library

> JSch is a pure Java implementation of SSH2.

[this example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/PortForwardingR.java.html) show the use of:

```
session.setPortForwardingR(rport, lhost, lport);
```